# Source(s) for Learning Cricket

Tags: rules, cricket, strategy

I would like to learn the game of cricket.  Not necessarily to play.  I enjoy watching it, but don't really understand what is going on.  I have watched some youtube videos that explain things, but I was wondering if anyone had a link or links to websites or videos that will explain things in depth (i.e. rules, strategy, variations of games (matches??), things like that).

Comment: I have this question too.  I need something that will help me understand what's exciting about it, and also a simple cheat sheet so I will understand episodes of "The Archers" from BBC4 where the characters are talking about a cricket match.  Wikipedia with its dense verbiage is absolutely the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cricket is a game played by two teams of 11 players each with [bat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_bat) and [ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_ball). Here, the scores are defined by [runs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_%28cricket%29). In the game, each team get a chance to [bat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batsman) and [bowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_%28cricket%29) which is called as *innings*. In the first innings the batting team try to score as much as possible while bowling team try to restrict their score as lower as possible. In the second innings the batting team try to chase/trail that score to win/lead the match.

In bowling side bowlers bowl balls to the batsmen. Each bowler can bowl maximum six legal balls in a row. This set of six legal balls is called as *over*. Bowling team try to take [wickets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dismissal_%28cricket%29) of the batting team. The innings ends as soon as 10 wickets are fallen.

There are main two types of cricket match: limited overs cricket and unlimited overs cricket.

In limited overs cricket there are two form of cricket [ODI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Day_International) and [T20I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty20_International). In ODI each team can bat for maximum 50 overs. While in T20I each team has 20 overs (as name suggests) to bat.

Unlimited overs cricket(international) is called as [Test cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_cricket). The test match is played for maximum 5 days. In test, each team get a chance to bat twice (two innings for each team). They can play for unlimited overs.

For more detailed information about cricket refer [this source by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket).